# How to get PictureBox's MouseDown event to work?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple 2d map editor, and the map is a grid of PictureBoxes.

```
        for (int row = 0; row < GlobalConstants.TileRows; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < GlobalConstants.TileCols; col++)
            {
                PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                pb.Size = size;
                Point loc = new Point(GlobalConstants.TileWidth * col, GlobalConstants.TileHeight * row);
                Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(loc, size); 
                pb.Location = loc; 
                pb.Tag = loc;
                pb.Name = String.Format("Col={0:00}-Row={1:00}", col, row);
                pb.MouseDown += pbMap_MouseDown;
                pb.MouseUp += pbMap_MouseUp; 
                pb.MouseEnter += pbMap_MouseEnter;
                pnlMap.Controls.Add(pb);
            }
        }
```

There are three mouse events:

MouseDown: Pressing down on a PictureBox fills the image with the selected item.
           m_mouseDown is set to true here.

MouseUp: m_mouseDown is set to false.

MouseEnter: While m_mouseDown is true, use the current selected tile and update the picturebox image.

I'm having a problem with MouseEnter:

```
    private void pbMap_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_mouseDown)
        {
            PictureBox pb;

            pb = (PictureBox)sender;

            if (m_pbSelected != null)
            {
                pb.Tag = m_pbSelected.Tag;
                pb.Name = m_pbSelected.Name;
                pb.Image = m_pbSelected.Image;
            }
        }
    }
```

While the first PictureBox image shows up on MouseDown, I keep the mouse button down and drag the mouse downward. The pictureboxes my mouse enters aren't updated. They only get updated on single clicks, but I would like them to get updated while the mouse button is kept pressed down.

If I remove the if (m_mouseDown) condition, the PictureBoxes do update the image to the selected image. Of course, I'm not pressing any buttons on the mouse while I move it. When I put the condition back in, only one picture box gets updated on a MouseDown event.

My mouse up/down code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Map panel's mouse down event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void pbMap_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_mouseDown = true; 

        MouseEventArgs m = (MouseEventArgs)e;
        PictureBox pb;

        if (m.X >= (GlobalConstants.TileWidth * GlobalConstants.TileCols))
            return;

        if (m.Y >= (GlobalConstants.TileHeight * GlobalConstants.TileRows))
            return;

        pb = (PictureBox)sender;

        if (m_pbSelected != null)
        {
            pb.Tag = m_pbSelected.Tag;
            pb.Name = m_pbSelected.Name;
            pb.Image = m_pbSelected.Image;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Map panel's mouse up event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void pbMap_MouseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_mouseDown = false;
    }
```

If it's important to mention, the pictureboxes are within a panel control. The panel has no mouse events.

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: While the button is down the mouse is 'captured' be the control where this happened and no mouseenter will happen. also the mouseUp will only happen to the original control, not where the mouse actually is. - Those are the rules. Before trying to work around, do state you actual gaol more clearly, please so we don't work on an  x-y-problem!! - _I keep the mouse button down and drag the mouse downward...Of course, I'm not pressing any buttons on the mouse while I move it._ Now which? This sounds contradictional to me!

Comment: Sooner or later, everyone discovers that PictureBox is a pretty lousy replacement for Graphics.DrawImage().  It could still be a bit useful for mouse hit testing, but when that starts to get in the way as well then it is truly time to dump it.

Comment: Based on a source code demo I obtained, it does work fine. Studying it currently.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this post. A similar question with an accepted answer is here [C# Windows Forms - MouseDownEvent with PictureBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72779128/5438626).

Answer (score 0):

You could make a timer to update the picture position to the cursor position on mouseDown, and stop the timer on mouseUp.