# C# Windows Forms - MouseDownEvent with PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I want to build an application to visualize searching algorithms (such as DFS, BFS) using C#.
I am using .cs files, and not xaml or xml.
So I made a matrix of 50X50 pictureboxes, each one has its own matrix indexes, and it's location on the gui window.
[image]

So this is my map so far.
What I'm trying to achieve is that every time I encounter MouseDownEvent, I want the specific picturebox to be chosen, and change it's color.
But I can't figure out how to do it.
I have my initBoard code:

```
private void initBoard()
{
    m_VisualizerPictureBox = new UpgradedPictureBox[m_BoardHeight, m_BoardWidth];
    int left = 0, top = (Top / 2 - m_BoardHeight);
    for (int i = 0; i < m_BoardHeight; i++)
    {
       left = Left / 2 - (m_BoardWidth - 1);
       for(int j = 0; j < m_BoardWidth; j++)
       {
           m_VisualizerPictureBox[i, j] = new UpgradedPictureBox(new Point(i, j))
                                              {
                                                  Size = m_ButtonSize,
                                                  Top = (i * m_ButtonSize.Width),
                                                  Left = (j * m_ButtonSize.Width),
                                                  Location = new Point(left, top),
                                                  BackColor = Color.Aqua,
                                                  BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                                              };
           left += m_ButtonSize.Width;
           m_VisualizerPictureBox[i, j].m_PositionOnBoard = new Point(i, j);
           int x = ((i + 1) * top) + left;
           int y = ((j + 1) * left) + top;
           Point XYPoint = new Point(x,y);
           m_VisualizerPictureBox[i, j].m_XYPosition = XYPoint;
           Controls.Add(m_VisualizerPictureBox[i, j]);
           int copyOfI = i, copyOfJ = j;
           m_VisualizerRectangles[i, j].Click += (sender, e) => buttonClicked(copyOfI, copyOfJ);
               m_VisualizerRectangles[i, j].MouseDown += (MouseDownEvent);
               m_VisualizerRectangles[i, j].MouseUp += (MouseUpEvent);
               m_VisualizerRectangles[i, j].MouseEnter += (mouseEnterEvent);
       }

       top += m_ButtonSize.Height;
    }
}
```

I don't want the user to press every single picturebox in a different press, I want the user to press his mouse, keep it down, and it will keep marking the pictureboxes as I need.

So I thought the next code should do it:

```
private void buttonClicked(int i_Row, int i_Col)
        {
            UpgradedPictureBox buttonClicked = m_VisualizerRectangles[i_Row, i_Col];
            if(m_VisualizerRectangles[i_Row,i_Col].BackColor == buttonClicked.m_DefaultBackColor)
            {
                m_VisualizerRectangles[i_Row, i_Col].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                m_VisualizerRectangles[i_Row, i_Col].BackColor = buttonClicked.m_DefaultBackColor;
            }
        }

        private void MouseDownEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_MouseIsDown = true;
            m_MouseIsUp = false;
        }

        private void MouseUpEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_MouseIsUp = true;
            m_MouseIsDown = false;
        }

        private void mouseEnterEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(m_MouseIsDown)
            {
                UpgradedPictureBox pictureClicked = sender as UpgradedPictureBox;
                int row = pictureClicked.m_PositionOnBoard.X;
                int col = pictureClicked.m_PositionOnBoard.Y;
                if(m_VisualizerRectangles[row, col].BackColor == pictureClicked.m_DefaultBackColor)
                {
                    m_VisualizerRectangles[row, col].BackColor = Color.Black;
                }
                else
                {
                    m_VisualizerRectangles[row, col].BackColor = pictureClicked.m_DefaultBackColor;
                }
            }
        }
```

However, the if statement at m_MouseIsDown is not letting me mark the pictureboxes when the mouse is pressed.
When I cancel this if statement, it lets me mark exactly how I want, but without my mouse being pressed.
What am I missing here?

Comment: You should validate that the MouseEnter event is actually happening. My quick test tells me that the MouseEnter won't fire with the mouse button down when it happens, it will come on after a MouseUp.  I don't have an actual solution for you right now though.

Comment: Don't use controls for this.  Just draw everything in one container and react to the mouse input for that one control.  Create a "Tile" class that allows you to know the position of each square, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're seeing this behavior because `PictureBox` tries to [Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.capture?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) the mouse on the `MouseDown` event. This is usually a "good" thing because it means the mouse down control will receive any and all mouse events until the mouse is released but in this case we don't want that.

If I understand correctly, you want to drag the mouse to see a result something like this:

[image: multiple squares colored by mouse]

I was able to achieve this outcome by setting the `Capture` property to `false` in the `UpgradedPictureBox` method that overrides the `MouseDown` event.

```
public class UpgradedPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        BackColor = Color.Fuchsia;
        Capture = false;
    }
    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            BackColor = Color.Fuchsia;
        }
    }
}
```

So maybe give this a try and test whether it works on your side.

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/matrix-30x30.git) this sample.

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was looking for the last week! I can't believe I went to write my code without knowing these basics. Thank you very much! It's working exactly as I wanted. :-)

Comment: I agree with @LarsTech that using an array of PictureBox might not be the most efficient, but managing the Capture will solve the problem.